# Django + Angular + Django-allauth

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm creating a web application using Django as the backend and Angular for the front.

Angular is running on a Yeoman stack on `localhost:9000` while Django is running on `localhost:8000` and I'm using `grunt-contrib-proxy` to redirect all the `$http` calls from  angular at `/api` to the django port. So for example, if Angular asks for `localhost:9000/api/hello` this will be redirect to `localhost:8000/api/hello`and django will serve it.

I'm planning to setup `Django Rest Framework` for serving all the Angular request to the `/api` path.

So far so good.

Now, I have an already configured and working installation of `Django-allauth` for making `Oauth` authentication to third party services. It does work using plain old Django but I have no idea how to make this work in conjunction with Angular.

The only thing that came into mind was serving the `allauth` views through django rest framework, but what about redirection after authentication? I can't wrap my mind around it.

Is it better to drop this approach and make the Oauth authentication straight from the front (Angular)?

**EDIT:**
I managed to call the `login` view from Angular

- In *grunt-contrib-proxy* I've added the *account* context and rewrite rule:

  ```
  context:  ['/api', '/accounts'],
  rewrite: {
    '^/api': '/api',
    '^/account': '/accounts'
  }
  ```
- I've made an ajax call from angular, asking for the allaluth login view (for example for github): `$http.get('/accounts/github/login/?process=login')`

The problem is that I get back:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=&state=BlaBla&redirect…ub%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&client_id=BlaBlaBla. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
```

(The BlaBla was added by me). I think I'm doing something totally wrong

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this issue? I'm trying to move a project that uses allauth over to angular and this is my biggest sticking point.

Comment: @FergalMoran No, I gave up for now. I've switched to [Python Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) + [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I've used [this blog post](http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api/) as starting point, good luck!

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, guess that's the way I'll have to go too. That blog post looks great, thanks!

Comment: hi there. have you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an

```
Origin: http://localhost:9000
```

to the header in the request that angular sends to Django.

Also make sure the server running Django returns an

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

[see here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).